# Python: store multi-line output in a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
data = ls['response']['resourceGroupResponseList']

for i in data:
   ls1 = (i['entities'])  
   ls2 = (', '.join(ls1))
   print (ls2)
```

It gives the output per the below:

```
datastore-206
datastore-586
datastore-207
datastore-826
datastore-205
datastore-2417
datastore-837
datastore-203
```

but from the console when I do `print (ls2)`, it only shows the last value, example below:

```
>>> print (ls2)
datastore-203
```

Is there a way to store all above multi-line values in a variable and pass it one by one through for loop.

example below:

```
for i in ls2.splitlines():
    print (i)
```

My code below:

```
data2 = ls['response']['resourceGroupResponseList']
for i in data2:
   ls1 = (i['entities'])
   ls2 = (', '.join(ls1))

for i in ls2:
    response = requests.get('https://website/'+i+'/search'), headers=headers, verify =False)
    ls3 = response.json()
    data3 = ls3['response']['backupResponseList']
    for i in data3:
       print(i['name'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each step of FOR loop you are reassign ls2 variable.
To store all lines in one list:

```
ls_store = []
for i in data2:
    # work with i and ls here
    ls_store.append(ls2)
```

After that FOR loop you will have a possibility to loop over results of it.

```
for ls_line in ls_store:
    # do what need with it :)
```

That's all. Ask if I misunderstood :)